# Is my LED strip broken?

Tags: power-supply, arduino, led-strip

I'm attempting my first ever electronics project, trying to do what's in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzDnr76fZCc). I have:

- A [WS2812B](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf) LED strip (60 LEDs/m), 5V
- An Alitov 5V 15A power supply
- An Arduino Nano
- Some little corner pieces to make right angles
- ...no wire strippers, so I do that with scissors. I need wire strippers. Also no multimeter.

I cut the strip into two pieces of 38 LEDs each and hook them up to the corner piece, making sure I follow the arrows on the strip. I then put the red wire into the positive terminal of the power barrel adapter, and the red/black wire into the negative terminal, and connect the two red/green/black wires via their connector. I plug it in... and nothing. The transformer block seems to be fine, it has a green light. But I have no idea if the strip is getting power or not.

[image]

Ok, maybe I need data? I flash my nano with a ColorPalette test code (from FastLED samples), and hook it up to the circuit as shown below (neutral/negative to ground pin, the green wire to D6 output pin)

[image]

Still nothing, and the nano shows no power LED as I expect it should (and like it does when I have it hooked up via usb). At this point I'm suspecting the power cable is borked, since it's a cheapo Amazon one (and to be fair, so is the LED strip). I am a complete beginner though so I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: `nano shows no power LED`, then don't be asking about LED strips ... get the nano working on its own first

Comment: ... and then with only one strip. You're not giving power to the Nano apparently. And do yourself a favor, don't put a red wire on a negative/ground connection.

Comment: Ok, I got it powered by hooking up the 5V pin to positive and the adjacent GND pin to negative. This... confuses me, since the wiring diagram in the video I'm following has no 5V pin connection at all... how should I hook it up to the LED strip now?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan In the video, the Arduino is powered from USB. But you can just as well power it from the power brick.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny ...yeah, that'll do it. Now I feel a bit silly. But at least I'm learning!